# Richfaces listshuttle custom button positioning

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have 2 issues with Richfaces shuttlelist component.

1:
I only want the following buttons available for a shuttle list - 'Copy', 'Remove', 'Move Up' & 'Move Down. The problem is Move Up & Down are displayed to the right of the 2nd list by default. I would like to have all four buttons in between the lists. Is there any easy way to do this?

2:
Additionally, for some reason my custom facets do not get applied when the page loads, only when i click on an item in a list do they get rendered. Any ideas why this is?

```
<rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{MyBean.filteredFieldsList}" sourceSelected="MyBean.selectedFields"
                    targetValue="#{MyBean.allSelectedFields}" targetSelected="MyBean.deSelectedFields" converter="TomsShuttleListConverter" 
                    listsHeight="180" sourceListWidth="260" targetListWidth="260" sourceCaptionLabel="Available Items" var="selectItems"
                    fastOrderControlsVisible="false" fastMoveControlsVisible="false" targetCaptionLabel="Currently Active Items"
                    copyControlClass="largerBtn">

    <f:facet name="copyControl">
        <h:outputText value="Add" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="removeControl">
        <h:outputText value="Remove" />
    </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="upControl">
        <h:outputText value="Move up" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="downControl">
        <h:outputText value="Move down" />
    </f:facet>


        <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{selectItems.label}"></h:outputText>
    </rich:column>          

</rich:listShuttle>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://community.jboss.org/message/610369#610369